# How to save Depth layer with sky?

Tags: export, compositing-nodes, image, workflow, depth-map

When I try to save it normally I get white image. Somebody advised to use normalize node and it works. But if sky is present (infinite depth) it doesn't normalize properly. I tried playing with map range and I get decent results but sky will always be pure black instead of pure white.

I want to save a depth layer to use as masks in photoshop. I wish it was easier to do in Blender. Blender can normalize them with no problem if I look at depth layer in rendered view, but I can't save it.